# menu access callback per role

Tags: users, routes

I'm trying to implement an access callback per role for a specific menu item, but other roles can view that menu item also. Any tip is welcome.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu();
 */
function MODULENAME_menu() {

  global $user;

  $items['admin/backoffice/production/taxonomie'] = array(
    'title' => 'Taxonomie',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 0,
    'page callback' => 'MODULENAME_backoff_taxonomy',
    'access callback' => 'MODULENAME_user_has_role',   
    'access arguments' =>  array($user, array('éditeur taxonomie', 'administrator')),
    );

  return $items;
}

function MODULENAME_backoff_taxonomy(){
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
  $form = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_overview_vocabularies');
  drupal_set_title('Backoffice - Taxonomie');
  return drupal_render($form);
}

function MODULENAME_user_has_role($user,$roles) { 
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a single `access callback` handle a dynamic number of roles which varies per menu link, try something like this in `hook_menu()`...

```
// hook_menu()
$items['foo'] = array(
  /* ... */
  'access callback' => 'MODULENAME_user_has_role',   
  'access arguments' =>  array('éditeur taxonomie', 'administrator'),
);
$items['bar'] = array(
  /* ... */
  'access callback' => 'MODULENAME_user_has_role',   
  'access arguments' =>  array('some other role'),
);
```

Then your `access callback` implementation:

```
function MODULENAME_user_has_role() { 
  global $user;
  $roles = func_get_args();
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```

That should do it.

**Some alternatives**

Remove the `global $user` and `access arguments` from `hook_menu()`.

Then change your `access callback` function implementation to this:

```
function MODULENAME_user_has_role() { 
  global $user;
  $roles = array('éditeur taxonomie', 'administrator');
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Since `hook_menu()` is invoked only when the menu router is being rebuilt (e.g. a cache clear, typically done by an admin or drush), `global $user` is not usually very useful from within that function. Instead, an `access callback` function is invoked at a more appropriate time (i.e. when the page is being viewed, or a menu link is about to be shown [or not] in a menu), at this point it is much easier to make a decision about the current user's context.

To make the `access callback` more generic, and be able to handle multiple menu link paths, I'll typically use a switch/case on an `arg()` to further curate the context:

```
switch (arg(3)) {
  case 'taxonomie':
    // do stuff...
    break;
}
```

Comment: this works fine thanks. I had done that because I wanted it to be more generic. I mean to pass `$role` from `$item` directly, so that I would have a single `MODULENAME_user_has_role()` for all the menu items....

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the dynamic approach you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A small addition I would make would be to do a check for UID = 1 like the rest of D7. A little late but hope it might helps some one.

```
function MODULE_user_has_role() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid == 1) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  $roles = func_get_args();
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```